# What if onsubmit event and onsubmit attribute both are defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What happens if onsubmit event and onsubmit attribute are both defined on a same form?

Lets say for example:-

```
<form id="cForm" name="cForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    function validate() {
        alert("validating");
        return true;            
    }

    $("#cForm").submit(function() {
        alert("another onsubmit");
        return false;   
    });
</script>
```

I tried this code in Firefox and it seems that both the functions are executed by `&&` operator.

Is it performing an 'and' operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If either one of them prevents the default action, then the form will not get submitted.

It is not actually an `and` operation, you can also make use of event.preventDefault() to get the same result.

Comment: will both the function always execute?